# JSON.stringify filter for properties with object values is not working

Tags: javascript, json

Can someone please clarify the rule of filtering?

property z is not being stringified properly, see last line pls.

MDN says "if an array, specifies the set of properties included in objects in the final string."

```
var obj = {x:1,y:'str',z:{a:1,b:2}};
var s = JSON.stringify(obj)
"{"x":1,"y":"str","z":{"a":1,"b":2}}"
var s = JSON.stringify(obj,["x","y","z"]);
"{"x":1,"y":"str","z":{}}"   //z empty object why?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), if `replacer`(the second parameter of JSON.stringify) is an array it specifies the set of properties included in objects in the final string.

You set it as `["x","y","z"]` in which case your resulting string has those three properties, what you may have missed is that it is applies to all properties not just those at the top level, so since you did not specify `"a"` and `"b"` in your array they where not included in the final string.

Try `JSON.stringify(obj,["x","y","z", "a", "b"]);` http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/rhCTY/

Comment: Thanks for clarification Musa, but a and b is not direct property of object. They should have mentioned :)

Comment: @Praveen: Well, they used *objects*, i.e. the plural of object. This somehow indicates that the property selection applies to all objects contained in the data structure.